# Separate xcodeproj file for iPhone and iPad sharing resources

Tags: iphone, universal

I am working on an iPhone application, latter to which i need to convert it into iPad application (Not universal)
I have seen somewhere a project that contains two separate xcodeproj file say

```
AppName_iphone.xcodeproj 
AppName_ipad.xcodeproj
```

in single folder that are sharing common files, but opens as separate application when i double clicks *.xcodeproj files.

I goggled for doing same but i can't find good resources that shows how to do that.

Please suggest good way of doing same.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this approach better than setting up multiple build targets inside one project?

Comment: @brigadir : according to my requirement i think yes it is.

Comment: i hope it may help you   http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/03/tutorial-part-2-same-xcode-project-create-multiple-products-for-iphone-using-script/

Answer (score 0):

or try this i think that could help you          http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

Comment: Thanks for help but that shows multiple build targets instead of multiple .xcodeproj files in single project.

Comment: do you check for the topic on the link    "Workspaces Extend the Scope of Your Workflow"  this will explain you the desired thing please check ..

Comment: Sorry as i was in hurry i didn't go through entire page. Workspace is good way of doing such task, but in my case its different, the project i am referring does not have any concept of workspace even have separate .xcodeproj file for both iPhone and iPad when i double click on each of these it opens in separate xcode. Thanks for your support.